# WPF: How to achieve a dependency property editng as a percentage/slider in the designer

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, blend

I have a dependency property of type double that expresses a percentage (0 to 1) in the designer (i.e. Expression Blend / Visual Studio)

It displays fine in the designer, as a 0 to 1 value, but I would like to show and have it editable as a "0%" to "100%" value, and even better if it could be displayed/edited as a slider (e.g. Opacity).

I'm thinking this would be done with a TypeConverter perhaps?  But not sure how to get the slider.  In either case, these capabilities would seem to be provided built-in, but I've not been able to find the magic sauce to annotate my property to get it to happen.

Comment: Where does this dependency property live? Is it part of a Custom Control/User Control you are creating, or is it part of some object which you are bound to?

Comment: It lives in a custom control (inherited from Panel) that I created.

Comment: Any specific reason you want to express it as 0 - 1?

Comment: rather than a byte 0 - 100 ? Do you need the precision of a double?

Comment: Is this a design time only property editor you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, design time.  Just this is an attempt to make the designer experience with the control better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Just realised you are talking about DesignTime editor.

Please see: [Creating Custom Editors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907382(v=vs.100).aspx)

More specifically: [Walkthrough: Implementing an Inline Value Editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546970(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: This is about the designer (Blend / VisualStudio)'s property inspector.  Not in the app.

Comment: A custom value editor may be the way to go, but given that there are already editors for exactly this (such as on the Opacity property when editing brush), I'm wondering if there is something more out-of-the-box I can associate with my property to get this effect.